# How can I test a flutter app using Google Mock?

Tags: flutter, googlemock

I want to test a flutter app. And recently I have heard about Google Mock and want to learn it. But first I want to know that can I test my flutter app using Google Mock?

Comment: I don't think gmock is available for dart.

Comment: Stackoverflows tag info: "Gmock is a mocking framework for Groovy. For questions relating to Google Mock, use tag [googlemock] instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gtest/Gmock is not used for Dart, but for C++ (and can somewhat be used for testing C).

Use instead Flutters built in framework for testing and use packages for mocking (such as Mockito).

Check https://flutter.dev/docs/testing for more info.